# Images in LaunchScreen.storyboard Disappear in Device

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

I put an image (my logo) in the launch screen storyboard file. The project was built using storyboard from the beginning. But I notice that the image does not appear when I test the app in my device. It appears ok in Storyboard though.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: does any answer help?

Comment: No..............

Answer (score 0):

Firstly clear `deriveddata` then delete your app from device. Then shutdown your device and restart it.It woks for me.Also you have follow UI guidelines of apple.

Answer (score 0):

The Image needs to be of exact size, replace your image with correct size and it will work.

You can check the size at: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

Comment: Sorry but my question is about LaunchScreen.storyboard. not the static image type.

Comment: Yes I got it, if the image are not of proper resolution as defined by apple it will not be displayed on app launch. Please try by having the exact resolution image and on launch the image will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the images from Assets.xcassets to project folder and set LaunchScreen.storyboard as imageName.png
Clear the derived data, clean the project,delete application from device.
Install application in device.
Let me know if you have any query.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for some reason it worked better to create a launch screen image with the proportions of an iPhone6 screen in Photoshop (or any other image manipulation program at your choice), and place it on the launch screen inside an `UIImageView` (and let it stick to it's superviews edges).